# xslt and xpath: match preceding comments

Tags: xslt, xpath

given this xml:

```
<root>
    <list>
        <!-- foo's comment -->
        <item name="foo" />
        <item name="bar" />
        <!-- another foo's comment -->
        <item name="another foo" />
    </list>
</root>
```

I'd like to use a XPath to select all item-nodes that have a comment immediately preceding them, that is I like to select the "foo" and "another foo" items, but not the "bar" item.

I already fiddled about the preceding-sibling axis and the comment() function but to no avail.

Comment: Note that in the XSLT/XPath data model those item elements you are looking for a not immediately preceded by a comment node but rather by a text node with white space.
So unless you use `<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>` in your stylesheets those white space text nodes can get in your way.

Comment: Good question (+1). See my answer for the only (at present) complete solution. Martin Honnen's comments are correct and although the currently-selected answer may work for you, it may suddenly stop doing so (if the XPath engine is provided with an XML document, whose white-space-only nodes aren't stripped off).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems to work:

```
//comment()/following-sibling::*[1]/self::item
```

It looks for immediately following siblings of comments which are also `<item>` elements. I don't know a better way to express the `::*[1]/self::item` part, which is ugly; note that if it were written `::item[1]` then it would also find `<item>`s not *immediately* proceded by a comment.

Comment: What happens if there is a processing instruction between the comment and the 'item' element? Certainly an edge case but the original poster first needs to clarify whether an 'item' element preceded by a processing instruction preceded by a comment is an element he wants to select.

Comment: @Kevin: Thanks, Kevin. This X-Path is simple enough for me to grasp, and it works perfectly :)
@Martin: Luckily I am the master of the Xml input, so I'm sure the won't be any processing instructions. Thanks anyway for the useful hint.

Answer (score 3):

**The currently selected solution**:

```
//comment()/following-sibling::*[1]/self::item
```

**doesn't work** in the case where there is a procesing instruction (or a whole group of processing instructions) between the comment and the element -- as noticed in a comment by Martin Honnen.

**The solution below doesn't have such a problem**.

The following XPath expression selects only elements nodes that are either immediately preceded by a comment node, or are immediately preceded by a white-space-only text node, which is immediately preceded by a comment node:

```
(//comment()
   /following-sibling::node()
     [1]
     [self::text()
    and 
     not(normalize-space())
     ]
      /following-sibling::node()
             [1] [self::item]
 ) 
|
(//comment()
   /following-sibling::node()
     [1]
     [self::item]
 )
```

**Here is a complete test**:

We use this XML document:

```
<root>
    <list>
        <!-- foo's comment -->
        <item name="foo" />
        <item name="bar" />
        <!-- another foo's comment -->
        <item name="another foo" />
        <!-- comment 3 --><item name="immed.after 3"/>
        <!-- comment 4 --><?PI ?><item name="after PI"/>
    </list>
</root>
```

**When the following transformation is applied on the above XML document**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>


 <xsl:template match="/">
   <xsl:copy-of select=
    "
    (//comment()
       /following-sibling::node()
         [1]
         [self::text()
        and
         not(normalize-space())
         ]
          /following-sibling::node()
                 [1] [self::item]
     )
    |
    (//comment()
       /following-sibling::node()
         [1]
         [self::item]
     )
    "/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
<item name="foo"/>
<item name="another foo"/>
<item name="immed.after 3"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in [this thread](http://www.velocityreviews.com/forums/t525667-xslt-selecting-nodes-matching-either-of-2-criteria.html), introducing a test (`<xsl:if test="..."></xsl:if>`) like:

preceding-sibling::comment()

would only tests whether the node *has* a preceding sibling that's a comment.

If you want to know, of the preceding siblings that are elements or comments, whether the nearest one is a comment, you could try:

```
(preceding-sibling::*|preceding-sibling::comment())[1][self::comment()] # WRONG
```

> BUT: that won't work, because though "`[1]`" means first in the backwards direction
>   for `preceding-sibling`, **it doesn't mean that for a parenthesized expression - it
>   means first in document order**

You can try:

```
(preceding-sibling::*|preceding-sibling::comment())[last()][self::comment()]
```

or

```
preceding-sibling::node()[self::*|self::comment()][1][self::comment()]
```

---

For instance:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" >
  <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="no" indent="no"/>

  <xsl:template match="//item">
    <xsl:if test="preceding-sibling::node()[self::*|self::comment()][1][self::comment()]">
      <xsl:value-of select="./@name" />
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

would only display:

```
foo
another foo
```

when typing:

```
C:\Prog\xslt\preceding-sibling_comment>
  java -cp ..\saxonhe9-2-0-6j\saxon9he.jar net.sf.saxon.Transform -s:test.xml -xsl:t.xslt -o:res.xml
```

with:

- `test.xml`: your file displayed in your question
- `t.xslt`: the xslt file above
- `res.xml`: the resulting transformed file

---

Edit: since it doesn't take into account processing instructions, I left that answer as Community Wiki.

Comment: Thanks for your thorough answer VonC! I tried the "if" construct and it works for me. I'd rather use the expression from Kevin though, as it is something I can understand (and hopefully remember).

Comment: This doesn't work in the situation described by Martin Honnen.

Comment: @Dimitre: +1 on your answer, and I leave mine as Community Wiki.